# Run jQuery effect inside callback of load function [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an external html code that I am loading it dynamically using load function of jQuery:

```
_this.load = function () {
    _this.view.container.load("html/index.html", function () {
            _this.view.loadAnimation();
    });
}

this.loadAnimation = function() {
    _this.heading = _this.container.find(".heading");
    _this.subheading = _this.container.find(".subheading");
    _this.reserve = _this.container.find(".reserve");

    _this.heading.addClass('hanimate');
    _this.subheading.addClass('sanimate');
    _this.reserve.addClass('ranimate');
}
```

Now the problem is that the function _this.view.loadAnimation(); is not running in the callback function of load. It works only if I add delay to the callback as the following:

```
_this.load = function () {
    _this.view.container.load("html/index.html", function () {
        $(window).delay(100).queue(function() {
            _this.view.loadAnimation();
        });
    });
}
```

I understand that all elements of inside "html/index.html" must be loaded before executing the loadAnimation();
The question is: isn't there a way or event that I can trigger when all elements of this "html/index.html" are loaded? into main div? how can I modify my code for this purpose?

**Update:** As requested, I have a an example in Codepen:
https://codepen.io/khaled85/pen/eyqQGz

Best,

Comment: Is your loaded `index.html` just plain static HTML, or is it calling other resources to populate its HTML?

Comment: yes! it contains only plain static html elements. I don't use database or anything alike! just a static html file on the directory

Comment: Does the load animation function need to be called only after loading index.html? If no, then you can use .ready jquery function

Comment: Can you post your code to a Codepen or JSFiddle please?  You don't need to post the "html/index.html" file, though. It would be helpful to get a bigger picture on your references in the code.

Comment: Marcus Parsons: Sure! I have posted a code in codepen. https://codepen.io/khaled85/pen/eyqQGz

Comment: Nagaraj Raveendran: yes, I need to start the animation after index.html is loaded. it has the elements which should animate